# Backpropagation: when to update weights?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

Could you please help me with a neural network?

If I have an arbitrary dataset:

```
+---+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| i | Input 1 | Input 2 | Exp.Output 1 | Exp.Output 2 | Act.output 1 | Act.output 2 |
+---+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1 |   0.1   |   0.2   |      1       |      2       |      2       |       4      |
| 2 |   0.3   |   0.8   |      3       |      5       |      8       |      10      |
+---+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Let's say I have x hidden layers with different numbers of neurons and different types of activation functions each.

When running backpropagation (especially iRprop+), when do I update the weights?  Do I update them after calculating each line from the dataset?

I've read that batch learning is often not as efficient as "on-line" training. That means that it is better to update the weights after each line, right?

And do I understand it correctly:  an epoch is when you have looped through each line in the input dataset?  If so, that would mean that in one epoch, the weights will be updated twice?

Then, where does the total network error (see below) come into play?

[[image](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~sgc/teaching/pre2012/v231/error.jpg), from [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~sgc/teaching/pre2012/v231/lecture13.html).]

---

*tl;dr*:
Please help help me understand how backprop works

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would update the weights after each example in the data set (I assume that's what you mean by each line).  So, for each example, you would see what the neural network thinks the output should be (storing the outputs of each neuron in the process) and then back propagate the error. So, starting with the final output, compare the ANN's output with the actual output (what the data set says it should be) and update the weights according to a learning rate.

The learning rate should be a small constant, since you are correcting weights for each and every example.  And an epoch is one iteration through *every* example in the data set.

Comment: Yip, "per line", I meant per example. So in the simple dataset I have here, I have two examples?
And thus, per epoch, the weights will be updated n times, with n = the number of examples, right?

Comment: If I then update the weights per line and I want to plot the error of the network (then I can see the error going lower, hopefully), which error do I plot? The error of each example?

Comment: You could average the errors together each epoch and see the general trend.